# Conversion in swift (id)initWithPreset:(int [])preset

Tags: iphone, swift

Can u convert - (id)initWithPreset:(int [])preset;
in Swift

```
int *type = nil;
    if (_selectedIndex == 0) {
        type = PRESET_PHONE;
    } 

extern int PRESET_FM[];
extern int PRESET_CD[];
extern int PRESET_STUDIO[];
extern int PRESET_VOICE[];
extern int PRESET_PHONE[];
extern int PRESET_TAPE[];
extern int PRESET_HIFI[];
```

In Objective c

```
  MP3Converter *mp3Converter = [[MP3Converter alloc] initWithPreset:type];
```

But I am using in Swift

```
var mp3Converter : MP3Converter!
            mp3Converter = MP3Converter(preset:PRESET_VOICE )
```

How we give there preset:PRESET_VOICE?. It gives the error Unsafe Immutable Pointer..

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the way you have defined the constant arrays.

You will need to define them as integer pointers, than arrays. Check:

```
//const int  PRESET_FM[] = {1, 2, 4, 5};  //<< This won't get exported to swift
const int * PRESET_FM = {1, 2, 4, 5}; //Swift can see this fine
```

And in your swift code, you will need to properly typecast this C constant to UnsafeMutablePointer as Swift will see the C pointers so.

```
var mp3Converter : mp3Converter = MP3Converter(preset:UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>( PRESET_FM)(PRESET_VOICE))
```

Also ensure the objective C interface to use int * than int[]:

```
- (id)initWithPreset:(int *)preset
```

HTH.